# Vue NUXT.JS, multiplicas funções em asyncData

Tags: vue.js

Sou iniciante em `Vue` com `Nuxt`, queria entender qual o problema nesse código que somente a primeira função funciona:

```
async asyncData () {

    const {data} = await axios.get('/api/skills/view')
    return {skills:data}


    return axios.get('/api/skills/5e5ff50f28767a288c6009ce')
    .then((res) => {
        return { title: res.data.habilidade, porcentagem: res.data.porcentagem }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só a primeira funciona por que você está dando o `return` na primeira função, depois desse ponto o que vier depois não é executado. Você pode usar o `await` igual fez na primeira função e depois dar só um `return` no final mesclando os dados:

```
async asyncData() {
    const {
        data
    } = await axios.get('/api/skills/view')

    const response = await axios.get('/api/skills/5e5ff50f28767a288c6009ce')

    return {
        title: response.data.habilidade,
        porcentagem: response.data.porcentagem,
        skills: data
    }
}
```

Você também pode desestruturar os dados:

```
async asyncData() {
    const {
        skills
    } = await axios.get('/api/skills/view')

    const response = await axios.get('/api/skills/5e5ff50f28767a288c6009ce')
    const { habilidade: title, porcentagem } = response.data
    return {
        title,
        porcentagem,
        skills
    }
}
```

`const { habilidade: title, porcentagem } = response.data` pega os valores `habilidade` e `porcentagem` de `response.data`, note que em `habilidade: title` estou renomeando o valor, criando uma variável com o nome de `title`, no fim passo os valores como resultado num único objeto.

Obs.: Não precisa repetir os valores na definição do objeto, dessa forma já funciona como esperado:

```
return {
    title,
    porcentagem,
    skills
}
```

Um outro detalhe importante, como você chama com `await`, o código só vai ser executado após terminar a primeira requisição, o valor da segunda não depende da primeira, você pode executar ambas e retornar o valor no final:

```js
const skillPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({
        data: {
            skills: ['skill1', 'skill 2']
        }
    })
})

const valuesPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({
        data: {
            habilidade: 'nome da habilidade',
            porcentagem: 50
        }
    })
})

function asyncData() {
    // const skillsPromise = axios.get('/api/skills/view')
    // const valuesPromise = axios.get('/api/skills/5e5ff50f28767a288c6009ce')
    Promise.all([skillPromise, valuesPromise]).then((results) => {
        const onlyData = results.map(result => {
            return result.data
        })
        const reducedObject = onlyData.reduce((result, current) => {
            return Object.assign(result, current)
        }, {})

        /*
          ou:
          const reducedObject = Object.assign({}, ...onlyData)
        */
        
        const {
            habilidade: title,
            porcentagem,
            skills
        } = reducedObject
        console.log({
            title,
            porcentagem,
            skills
        })
    })
}

asyncData()
```

Usei a função `Promise.all` passando as chamadas do `axios` (no exemplo eu precisei criar as promises só por demonstração), o `Promise.all` retorna um array com os resultados em caso de sucesso, como queremos apenas o valor de `data` das chamadas do axios eu faço um map para pegar só esse valor, no fim o utilizo `reduce` junto com o `Object.assign` para mesclar os dados.

Comment: Boaa, pensei em fazer a mudança do return para const, e percebi que era o return msm hehe, thanks!